# Entity lighting bug or invisible entity parts or just like that

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I newly moved to zorin os and now I am facing to some issues about minecraft.
whenever I walk near an entity, it becomes white or some part of it dissapears .
like :
[image: invisible boat part]

or :

[image: My Blury Legs in F5 mode]

or in menu :

[image]

So What should I do ?

Comment: Hi, this is still a new question, having barely 1/2 day. I would suggest waiting longer. This seems to be a either graphics card problem as haven't found anything online or a OS problem, which would be hard to debbug for us, since I would say the chances of someone also having Zorin might be low. Questions here aren't always answered in the same day when they are this specific/complex. If you are in a rush, Those are my recommendations to look for: Graphics card or OS problem.

Comment: Thanks For Your informing, I Havent Bean in This Siye For Too Long, But I could Not Find AnyThing Online, and Another Thing Is I Was Runnging It On My Windows Os perfectly, But Zorin Is Based On Ubuntu That I Think It Does Not Have Those Problems, I Dont Know How To Solve It, And Sorry For Trash English

Comment: Oh, I just noticed. Your game seems to be modded, what mods do you have it on? Does turning them off resolve your problem? Better, what happens if you play vanilla on this version.

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues yes I played Vanilla and thought if I mod the game with sodium it will help but both of them are broken

Comment: No One ????????????????!!!1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but when I used **21W10a** it appears to be fixed.

Comment: This answer could be posted as comment under your question, but I guess it solves your problem? Either way, try re-installing the version of minecraft that is glitchy. (Be sure to save all worlds in another folder)

Comment: I did not know versions can cause this.
I would do it.

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues I did it but nothing happend, deleted game files and downloading it again did not do it, any suggestion ?